# Result display showing weird with sql : Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to do some analysis with spark. I tried the same query with foreach which shows the results correctly but if I use show or in sql it is weird, it is not showing anything.

```
sqlContext.sql("select distinct device from TestTable1 where id = 23233").collect.foreach(println) 

[ipad]
[desktop]
[playstation]
[iphone]
[android]
[smarTv]
```

gives proper device but if I use just show or any sql :

```
sqlContext.sql("select distinct device from TestTable1 where id = 23233").show()

%sql
select distinct device from TestTable1 where id = 23233

+-----------+
|device     |
+-----------+
|        |
|    |
|ion|
|       |
|    |
|     |
+-----------+
```

I need graph and charts, so I would like to use %sql. But this is giving weird results with $sql. Does any one have any idea why I am getting like this ?

Comment: Are there anything special in your data, like some invisible prefix? sqlContext.sql("select distinct job from bank").show work perfect on Zeppelin Tutorial notebook.

Answer (score 0):

`show` is a formatted output of your data, whereas `collect.foreach(println)` is merely printing the `Row` data. They are two different things. If you want to format your data in a specific way, then stick with `foreach`...keeping in mind you are printing a sequence of `Row`. You'll have to pull the data out of the row if you want to get your own formatting for each column.

I can probably provide more specific information if you provide the version of spark and zeppelin that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you are using `%sql` because you need Zeppelin's graphs and charts--i.e. you wouldn't be swapping to `%sql` if you didn't have to.

You can just stick with using Spark dataframes by using `z.show()`, for example:

```
%pyspark 

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
                                    (23233, 'ipad'), 
                                    (23233, 'ipad'),
                                    (23233, 'desktop'), 
                                    (23233, 'playstation'),
                                    (23233, 'iphone'),
                                    (23233, 'android'),
                                    (23233, 'smarTv'),
                                    (12345, 'ipad'),
                                    (12345, 'palmPilot'),
                                ], ('id', 'device'))

foo = df.filter('id = 23233').select('device').distinct()
z.show(foo)
```

In the above, `z.show(foo)` renders the default Zeppelin table view, with options for the other chart types.